# Pass PHP variables from HTML to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-blade

I want to do something to 'input box' when the radio button is checked, so I'm thinking using JS to solve this, here's part of my HTML code:

```
<input type="radio" class="icheck" id='DELIVER_{{$shoppingcart->id}}' />
```

$shoppingcart->id is from database, so the ID is dynamic, so now I'm using JS like:

```
var deliverId = DELIVER_{{ $shoppingcart->id }};
if(document.getElementById(DELIVER_{{$shoppingcart->id}}).checked) {

    //do something

else if (...)
...
```

but the error is 'shoppingcart is not defined', how can I define it or solve the issue?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I'm using blade and new to this template, how can I pass variables between HTML and JS?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the id on radio box using querySelectorAll
`document.querySelector('icheck').id`
and then iterating over all the available radio buttons

```
for(var i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll('.icheck').length;i++){
  var deliverId=document.querySelectorAll('.icheck')[i].id;
  if(document.getElementById(deliverId).checked) {

    //do something

  else if (...)
  ...
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: The return value of `getElementByClassName` is not an element object, so that won't work.

Comment: hmm, then we can use querySelector('.icheck'), this will return an element

Comment: but I have multiple radio buttons, they are siblings and using same class, what kind of selector should I use? Thank you! @Mohd Asim Suhail